# Polymer 1.0 updating properties with wrapped object

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, word-wrap

Let's say that I have some custom element like this:

```html
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  MyElement = Polymer({
 is: 'my-element',

 properties: {
  posX:{
   type: Number,
   reflectToAttribute: true,
   notify: true,
   compute: '_posXChanger(obj)'
  },

  obj: {
   type: Object
  }
 },

 _posXChanger: function(obj){
  this.posX = obj.getBBox().x;
 },

 attached: function(){
  this.obj = new SomeObject(/*coordinates*/this.posX,100);
 }
});
</script>
```

I have implemented behavior to SomeObject so I can move it wherever I want. But I also want that when I will move it, attribute pos-x gets updated according to my SomeObject position in canvas. Now there is only first value and it is not changing, my SomeObject is working correctly, only attribute is not getting updated. Also when I am looking at it through dev tools, it always tells me

> my-element 0px x 0px

How will I do it? Is it even possible? Am I missing something?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: How/where is the SomeObject position being updated? How you can listen to changes on SomeObject will depend on how SomeObject's position is being changed. If you could share that could, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Dogs I will share my code just need to set my git repository to public.  Work on project has ended, so I can share my sources in a few days.